# Rasterpropmonitor for Kerbal Space Program

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Hello people I am a player of the PC game kerbal space program. I don't use many mods so I am unfamiliar with the process. I have download the rasterpropmonitor.zip, uncompressed it with 7-zip then move the unzipped folder into the gamedata file, I boot up the game but all the monitors are missing. I can't seem to find help with this anywhere. I am using the latest version (0.24). Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use the Comprehensive Kerbal Archive Network to install your mods.  You can find the latest release on Github.  https://github.com/KSP-CKAN/CKAN

It will manage any dependencies and help you keep them up to date.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the mid was created for a later version of the game, I suggest you wait a week or two for the modder to update the game files, alternatively Look at read me file in the mod zip and see if a different location is specified.

Comment: I tried the read me but it didn't help

Comment: Try locate the original forum form where it came and see if the creator has updated the mod or if it is required

Comment: I've located the forum and there is a source code. Should I put that in the mod. The forum doesn't say

Comment: No its the source code that is the problem I think, if nothing try and re download and install the mod again, perhaps the file was corrupted

Comment: Tried it. I know the mod works because everything else works besides the monitors, which are important

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm understanding, but if you're saying that where the monitors should be is just black, There are buttons around the monitors. Since each monitor serves multiple purposes, you have to click those buttons to see anything.